# Bash: grep odd numbers that are 5 digit or longer

Tags: bash, grep

I have file called numbers.txt and below are the content

```
2
4
6
5
123
2316548
21321
266547
```

For all 5 digit or larger number

```
grep -E [0-9]\{5,\} numbers.txt
```

For all odd numbers

```
grep -E [13579]$ numbers.txt
```

Now how can I combine the result of the two or do it all in one line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do. I changed a bit the syntax on grep, so you don't escape, but rather en-quote.

```
grep -E "[0-9]{4,}[13579]$" numbers.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```bash
grep -E [0-9]\{4,}[13579]$ numbers.txt
```

Match 4 character of 0-9, then an odd digit and finally end of line.